# How can I search for taggable_friends (FB API) form within my app without using a limit on my request?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently using Facebook's OpenGraph to obtain taggable_friends. By default and as of FB API > 2.1 the request only returns 25 objects. You can add a limit and increase your data response but you have no parameters you can pass. It just doesn't feel right to increase the limit with a hard coded number. So, one of the features of that app is that you can search for taggable_friends and select them. If you return a large limit to obtain (in most cases) all of your friends can take a while. Let's say you only get the first 25 and you search for a person that is in a batch - you don't know where. Since you have no parameters to pass to your request, a searchTerm for your your API call is out of the question.

1. Has anyone ever done a batch call? Facebook allows for multiple requests using some sort of batch calls. How would that look like in JS code?
2. I can use my users information to obtain the amount of friends he/she has and set a reasonable limit. That helps in the majority of cases but doesn't solve the problem.

Did someone ever encounter that problem and solved it?

Comment: You should only fetch more taggable friends if the user desires so (e.g. if the scroll to the end of the list, or if they click "load more"). For the rest, you should follow the documentation on paging [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#paging)

Comment: The requirement is to search within an existing group of friends.